# Trigger ajax action by url or link

Tags: ajax

I currently have a page which has a block with taxonomy terms displayed.  Each link has been made to work with ajax to display information below if clicked, generated in a module callback.

What I am trying to acheive is also have this work if linked to.  So for example my page URL is currently http://localhost/events/building01 
If someone was to visit http://localhost/events/building01/printer then the information for printer would be displayed under the taxonomy term as it would if someone had clicked on the term.

My ajax links are currently setup like:

```
function building_block_menu() 
{
  $items['events/%/%/ajax'] = array(
  'title' => 'ajax call',
  'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
  'page callback' => '_event_ajax_callback',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['events/%/%/nojs'] = array(
  'title' => 'nojs call',
  'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
  'page callback' => '_event_nojs_callback',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
function _event_ajax_callback($building, $type)
{
  $markup = $building . ' - ' . $type;
  $ajax_commands = array();
  $ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_html('#ajax-target', $markup);
  ajax_deliver(array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $ajax_commands));
}
function _event_nojs_callback() 
{
  return "no js to be built";
}
```

And called from links built like:

```
$output .= l($term->name, 'events/$building/'.$term->tid.'/nojs', array(
            'attributes' => array('id' => 'building-term-'.$term->tid, 'class' => 'use-ajax')
            ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would be to add an ID to each link like `link_printer` and then use jQuery to parse the url, get the last fragment, and click any links that match.

```
var splitURL = window.location.href.split('/');
var link_id = '#link_' + splitURL[splitURL.length - 1];
if ($(link_id).length > 0) document.querySelector(link_id).click();
```

Comment: That works for me.  Do you know if this would work for search engine crawlers as well? Or would I need to look at creating a more complicated solution using the HTML5 history API?